# Having issues trying to convert a binary search tree into a balanced search tree with just one method in python

Tags: python

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, left_child=None, right_child=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left_child = left_child
        self.right_child = right_child
        self.height = -1



class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.height = -1
        self.balance = 0    


    def inorder(self):
        return self.inorder_helper(self.root)

    

    def inorder_helper(self, cur_node):
        lyst = []
        if cur_node is not None:
            lyst += self.inorder_helper(cur_node.left_child)
            lyst.append(str(cur_node.data))
            lyst += self.inorder_helper(cur_node.right_child)

        final_lyst = list(map(int, lyst))
        return final_lyst

    def rebalance_tree(self):
        arr = self.inorder()
        return self.rebalance_tree_helper(arr)

    def rebalance_tree_helper(self, arr):

        if not arr: 
            return None        

        mid = (len(arr)) // 2


        root = Node(arr[mid])
        

        root.left_child = self.rebalance_tree_helper(arr[:root])

        root.right_child = self.rebalance_tree_helper(arr[root + 1:])

        return root

bst.add(5)
bst.add(10)
bst.add(12)
bst.add(20)
bst.rebalance_tree()

print(bst)
```

Having issues trying to convert a binary search tree into a balanced search tree. So i currently have a binary search tree and it works correctly, 100%. However, I am trying to add a method that will balance the tree (aka turn it into an avl tree).

So i tried using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/ and tried making it a method into a tree, but i am having a few issues.

it keeps saying that i am reaching the recursion limit, and this is worrying me as i added these few lines of code that makes the recursion limit a lot higher then it should be needed:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (2**29,-1))
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

So now I am wondering if my method is running infinitely and causing the recursion limit, but i took a long look at the rebalance_helper and it looks like its not infinite.

If anyone can give me any insight i would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: "it looks like its not infinite" when do you believe it will terminate? Maybe I'm missing something, but it always unconditionally calls itself...

Comment: because itll eventually return all of the roots. Look at the edited code @junpa

Comment: What? That doesn't make any sense. You **always** call `rebalance_tree_helper()` twice... why do you expect it not to keep calling `rebalance_tree_helper`? Let me reword it, what do you think the base case in `rebalance_tree_helper` is?

Comment: uhh..  when its been through all of the nodes? What is the base case in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/ (python) because i really am just trying to replicate that but making it a method instead of a function

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear: that function will never stop calling itself. "When it's been through all the nodes", ok, imagine that's true... why will it **not call** `root.left_child = self.rebalance_tree_helper(arr[:root])`?? It **always does that**. Unconditionally.

Comment: If you are talking about `sortedArrayToBST` then the base case is `if not arr:`...

Comment: okay, i added the if not arr:.... to the edited code, ran it, and i am still hitting the recursion limit. any ideas? mid = (len(arr)) // 2
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You are going to have to provide a [mcve] ... note, `arr[:root]` doesn't make any sense, and should throw an error before you even enter the recursion.